# How do I convert a private key generated with CSR into a PEM format?

Tags: amazon-web-services, openssl, ssl-certificate, amazon-elb, pem

I wish to install my SSL certificates on to my webserver which is hosted on AWS. All the tutorials I've looked at online want me to convert my certificates and private key into PEM format before uploading.

I'm running into some issues along the way.

1. I am using this command to convert the cert files into PEM

   ```
              openssl x509 -inform PEM -in DigiCertCA.crt
   ```

The only problem is I have no idea if it's really working or not. After I hit enter, I get a

```
         -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----

              {FAT STRING HERE}

         -----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

output on the console and that's it. I don't know what to do, so I copied the certificate details that were printed and pasted it into a text editor and saved it as cert.PEM. This approach feels cheap, and I don't have a lot of faith in it, so please educate me on the correct approach.

2. The next question I have is regarding the private key needed when installing SSL certificates.
   I used an online tool to generate the CSR for the SSL certificates. I copy-pasted both the CSR and the private key into .txt files. When I try to convert the private key into a PEM file using the same command I mentioned earlier, I get an error.

unable to load certificate
6088:error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line:crypto\pem\pem_lib.c:745:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE

So I switched up the syntax and used this line instead:

```
              openssl rsa -inform PEM -in server.key
```

I get an output similar to the other one, except this time it's a little different:

```
         -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY------

              {FAT STRING HERE}

         -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY------
```

I do not know what an RSA key is but is this okay?

3.How do I upload / install the certificates?
A common solution I have seen for this is either through the ACM portal using the AWS console. Another approach I've seen is using the command line.

aws iam upload-server-certificate –server-certificate-name my-server-cert –certificate-body file://my-server-certificate.pem –private-key file://my-private-key.pem –certificate-chain file://my-certificate-chain.pem

That is the command used but I'm not sure how this will upload my certificates to AWS... Is it like connecting servers to github repos where they'll ask me for the username and password for the AWS account and then from there the files will just know where to go?

4. What Is an elastic load balancer? Will I need to configure it in order for my SSL certificates to work? Will it charge my AWS account?

I know this is asking a lot but please help out if you can. I'm a newb developer stuck with amateur problems.

Thank you!

Comment: In both commands you're using "-inform PEM", so the contents are already PEM encoded.  The output, which starts and ends with text like `-----BEGIN SOMETHING----- / -----END SOMETHING-----` is what it means to be PEM encoded.

Comment: Hmm so if the file already starts and ends with the -----BEGIN SOMETHING----- / -----END SOMETHING----- then I can upload them as is and they should work?

Comment: Yep. If it doesn’t work then you’ll probably need a new, more specific question that says what kind of file you have (e.g. what the “SOMETHING” actually is) and what the error is. But your data is already PEM encoded.